# adverb of frequency

Tags: word-usage

> Great good luck sometimes touches a person at least once.

It is from "Dreams Do Come True" by Jim Bishop.

I want to know the frequency adverbs "sometimes" and "once" are  the same and I can drop ot "sometimes"
in this sentence or change "sometime".

Comment: The statement is unclear. Sometimes great clarity touches a person at least once, and this was not one of those times.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that having both "sometimes" and "once" to modify the same verb *feels* contradictory, so this is not a great sentence. But it is what it is. Both might be necessary to express the writer's intent, which I can only imagine is something like:

> Over a period of time, a person will experience regular, extraordinary good luck, and this period will happen at least once in every person's life.

At least this is my best guess, assuming the author is writing seriously.  Is this profound?  Is it a kind of a joke?  It could be that the contradiction between the two adverbs is intentional and meant to imply something deep and significant to the author.  Or, like some authors, he might just be playing with words because, to him, it simply *sounds* good.

Outside of context I can't tell, so I won't judge.

Comment: What exactly is the OP asking? Usually I'm quite adept at interpreting learners' requests, and if I don't fully understand I will post a clarificatory comment or make an edit. It seems that you and @endofthecode have both clearly understood. But nowhere do I see the OP mentioning "contradictory", or "why", or about "meaning" in their question.  As far as I can tell, the OP is asking if the adverb *sometimes* can either be omitted or replaced by a different one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There are two adverbs in the sentence that both modify "touches".  "Sometimes" means "infrequently" while "at least once" can mean "very infrequently".  So which does the author mean?  Once in a while, or just once (maybe twice), period?  It's difficult to understand unless you read between the lines and *interpret* -- which is why I say it's poor writing.  With good writing, you shouldn't have to guess unless the author is *trying* to be allegorical or cryptic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA so what I think learner is asking is one of the two adverbs is redundant, or else should he change "sometimes" to another adverb that adds meaning, perhaps "fortuitously" or "happily"

Comment: It could well be that is the correct interpretation of the OP's request, it makes sense, but are you *sure* that is what the OP meant? Unless you edit the question or ask him directly, how will language learners understand

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, learner. This is a sentence that could ignite controversy among traditionalists (people who follow grammar strictly) and people like myself. I'll try to explain the two perspectives.

Remember, first of all, that "sometimes" and "once" have different meanings and different tenses. "Once" is past tense and occurs exactly one time, while "sometimes" is usually present tense and happens occasionally. Perhaps you already knew that, so let's dig deeper.

> Great good luck...

This is a stylistic way of saying "incredible luck." The word "good" is unnecessary" and I would assume that my students simply made a mistake, however we usually trust that published authors meant to do this on purpose. Maybe they wanted a certain rhythm, style or emphasis. Let's simplify:

> Great luck *sometimes touches a person*...

This means that fantastic things happen to people from time to time.

> Great luck sometimes touches a person *at least once*.

Now we can say that these fantastic things may happen to people only one time, but perhaps more.

> (1) Great good luck (2) sometimes touches a person (3) at least once.

While traditional editors might rewrite the sentence ("Great luck sometimes touches a person."), we can see that the author has created *tension*. Beyond the context of this individual sentence, we the readers now expect that:

1. The writer will have a non-traditional style, and thus the story might be 'fantastical' as well.
2. Some incredible stroke of luck might arrive at the doorstep of our lead character.
3. This lead character might be lucky not once, but more than once.